# why the below code is printing the first value alone in all iterations?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

```
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item']"));
System.out.println("Number of Items : " + listItems.size());
         
for(WebElement e : listItems ) 
{
 String sTextValue = e.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item_name']")).getText();
 System.out.println(sTextValue);
}
```

While iterating, it prints the 1st item name alone for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate element inside other element with XPath you should use a dot `.` at the beginning of the internal element XPath as following.
This should work:

```java
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='inventory_item']"));
System.out.println("Number of Items : " + listItems.size());
         
for(WebElement e : listItems ) 
{
 String sTextValue = e.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='inventory_item_name']")).getText();
 System.out.println(sTextValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try like this :

```
int i = 0;
for(WebElement e : listItems) 
{
    String sTextValue = e.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='inventory_item']//div[@class='inventory_item_name'])['"+i+"']")).getText();
    i++;
    System.out.println(sTextValue);
}
```